# Using raw GNSS Measurement could one potentially increase sample rates?

Tags: android, gps, android-gnss

I'm looking for ways to increase the position sample rate using an android phone. How to get a higher sample rate has been asked before about once a year here at SO.

But my question is more specific. By using the new [Raw GNSS Measurements](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/gnss.html) would it be possible to get a higher sample rate if I use the raw data and calculate the position myself?

Maybe I have misunderstood the point of the raw GNSS data, but in my ignorance I'm thinking that a phone like the Pixel 2 which supports data from GPS, GLONASS, GALILEO, BeiDou & QZSS should theoretically get the data much more frequent than 1Hz. But the chip it self only calculates and send positions to the system at a 1Hz sample rate.

But since there is the raw data from five positioning systems it should be possible to not only get a higher sample rate but also more accuracy!?!?!?

So my question is if its possible, using the raw data, to get higher sample rates and better accuracy? Reading through the page above doesn't suggest much about it and Raw positioning data is not a specialty of mine.

Answer (score 0):

The interval for raw GPS updates really depends on the internal GPS receiver's capabilities.  No matter what feature Android provides, it can't invent more samples than the receiver provides.

Secondly, by supporting multiple satellite constellations, there is a higher chance that you will obtain a 3D fix - because there is more to choose from by the receiver - but that is not guaranteed.  For example, if you are driving in downtown Manhattan N.Y., being surrounded by tall buildings will reduce satellite visibility across the board.  Combining low precision samples from multiple constellations to generate high precision data would be quite complicated (I won't say impossible though).

I don't know if modern receivers perform this sort of combination, so I typically do not assume they do.  And relegating this complex computation to your application - via Raw GNSS measurements - would be an interesting experiment...